# Посылка http запроса через определенный интерфейс

Tags: android, http, retrofit, wifi, 3g

При разработке приложения, используя Retrofit2 для http запросов к серверу, возникли следующие вопросы.

1. Возможно ли исходящие от устройства запросы посылать на определенный интерфейс (3G/4G или Wifi)?
2. Принятый от сервера ответ, к примеру 3G, переадресовывать на Wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, это все возможно только начиная с Андроид 5.

Есть официальная статья по теме:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/connecting-your-app-to-wi-fi-device.html

Вас заинтересует последний раздел.

> **Routing network requests**
>
> To direct all the network requests from your app to an external Wi-Fi device, call **ConnectivityManager#setProcessDefaultNetwork** on Lollipop devices, and on Marshmallow call **ConnectivityManager#bindProcessToNetwork** instead, which is a direct API replacement. Note that these calls require android.permission.INTERNET; otherwise they will just return false.